# how can i know how often (if statment are True) in my code?

Tags: python

Let's assume:

```
for a in range(10):
  if a == 2 or a == 5:
    print (how often this condition was True)
```

of course will be two, in my code i want to know when my condition be True , thanks

Comment: initialize a `counter = 0`, and then add a `counter = counter + 1` inside your `if` statement.

Comment: `sum(a == 2 or a == 5 for a in range(10))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count = 0 # set a variable for counting

for a in range(10): 
  if a == 2 or a == 5: # for each entry that meets the condition
    count += 1         # add 1 to count
print(count)           # 2
```